# Python3でサーバ時刻と現在時刻のずれで発生すると思われるエラーを解決したい

Tags: python

発生しているエラーメッセージ

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/flilhack/\u540d\u79f0\u672a\u8a2d\u5b9a\u30d5\u30a9\u30eb\u30bf\u3099/tes.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(get_spreadsheet_data())
  File "/Users/username/flilhack/\u540d\u79f0\u672a\u8a2d\u5b9a\u30d5\u30a9\u30eb\u30bf\u3099/tes.py", line 23, in get_spreadsheet_data
    wsheet        = gfile.get_worksheet(0)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/v4/models.py", line 138, in get_worksheet
    sheet_data = self.fetch_sheet_metadata()
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/v4/models.py", line 120, in fetch_sheet_metadata
    r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/v4/client.py", line 67, in request
    endpoint, json=json, params=params, data=data, files=files
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 226, in cert_verify
    "invalid path: {0}".format(cert_loc))
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
[Finished in 0.597s]
tes.py26:1
LFUTF-8Python0 files3 updates

oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError
```

---

該当のソースコード(Python3)

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def get_spreadsheet_data():
    doc_id        = '[spreadsheet URL のid]'
    json_key_path = '/Users/username/Downloads/My Project-a5bcde8be455.json'
    scope         = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    credentials   =  ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_key_path, scope)
    gclient       = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    gfile         = gclient.open_by_key(doc_id)
    wsheet        = gfile.get_worksheet(0)
    records       = wsheet.get_all_records(head=1)
    return records

print(get_spreadsheet_data())
```

---

試したこと

似たようなエラーがないかを確認したところ、スタックオーバーフローの本家の方で時刻のズレが原因ということを発見いたしました。わたしは現在Mac10.13.3を使用しており、日付と時刻の環境設定から自動設定にて設定しております. 手動設定なども試しましたが解決には至りませんでした。

---

使用環境

- OS Mac10.13.3
- Python3
- Atom

Comment: `raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must bea short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe`みたいなエラーではありませんでしたか？

Comment: Haru様。コメントおよびご回答いただきありがとうございます。そのようなエラーメッセージは今の所見当たりません。追記なのですが、以下のエラーメッセージがでています。OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path

Comment: 先程と似たようなエラーですね。path;以下も同じ文章なのでしょうか？それと、[http://blog.vero4ka.info/blog/2017/08/03/abrir-hojas-de-calculo-de-google-desde-python/]のように、try文でくくってエラーを逃がしてみるとどうなるんでしょうか？

Comment: Haru様、ご返信ありがとうございます。くくるというとどこでしょうか。

Comment: 追記 : エラー全文を載せました。ご確認いただけましたら幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あら、申し訳ありません。なぜか、文が途中で切れていました。リンクをたどっていただけたら、try...except文でエラー回避をしているのが分っていただけると思いますが、エラーが発生するコードをくくっていただけたらと思ったのです。

Comment: ログの前半、`tes.py`の置かれているパスが日本語混じりか何かで化けているようなので、実行時に処理が失敗している可能性があります。別の場所（パスに半角英数しか含まない）に保存して実行するとどうなるでしょうか。

Comment: まず、「時刻のズレが原因」との判断の根拠となったStackOverflowの投稿のURLをお願い致します。また、Anaconda をご利用のようなので、そのバージョンなどもあった方がよさそうです。
エラーを見る限り、`conda` での `certifi` のインストールがうまくいっていない気がします。
とりあえず `conda update conda`、`conda update --all` をやって見るのもよいかも知れません。

Comment: ちょっと追加しました。御覧ください。

Comment: ただいま試行しております、誠にありがとうございます。また結果を報告させていただきたく思います。

Comment: 役に立つかわかりませんが、[https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi]で、２０１８年１月１８日に更新されたcertifiについてダウンロードできるようです。おそらくpipでgspreadをインストールしたときと同じ要領でインストールができませんか？もしかしたらエラーが改善するかもしれません。

Comment: Haru様、コメントありがとうございます。同じ要領でインストールできました。エラーの改善に取り組んでみます。

Comment: 1.pathの半角英語を修正いたしました。2.conda update --allインストールをいたしました。ここでなのですが、少し不可解なものを発見いたしましたので報告いたします。　　　　　　　　　　conda update --allを実行しましたところ、最後の方に OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundleのエラーが出ました。これは何か関係がございますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

少し書く時間がないのですが、こちらも参照してください。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356116/mac-py2app-not-finding-cacert-pem
これは、[最近修正された](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4369)requets内のバグですが、まだリリースされたバージョンでは修正を行っていません。もしあなたがrequestsの開発バージョンを使ってOKなら、github repoからインストールすることができますよ。

> This was a bug in requests that was recently fixed but has not made it to a release version yet. If you are ok with using a development version of requests, you can install from the github repo (upgrading if already present) so that when you build your app you have the latest version with this fix:

```
pip install -U https://github.com/requests/requests/zipball/master
```

また、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119901/python-requests-cant-find-a-folder-with-a-certificate-when-converted-to-exe

> I ran into this problem as well. It looks like it comes from the certificate bundle cacert.pem not being included in the requests package directory when the program is compiled. The requests module uses the function certifi.core.where to determine the location of cacert.pem. Overriding this function and overriding the variables set by this function seems to fix the problem.

自分のプログラムの初めにこのコードを追加しましたとあります。

I added this code to the beginning of my program:

```
import sys, os


def override_where():
    """ overrides certifi.core.where to return actual location of cacert.pem"""
    # change this to match the location of cacert.pem
    return os.path.abspath("cacert.pem")


# is the program compiled?
if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
    import certifi.core

    os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = override_where()
    certifi.core.where = override_where

    # delay importing until after where() has been replaced
    import requests.utils
    import requests.adapters
    # replace these variables in case these modules were
    # imported before we replaced certifi.core.where
    requests.utils.DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH = override_where()
    requests.adapters.DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH = override_where()
```

(前の投稿↓）
日本語では、[[Python] gspreadでGoogle Spreadsheetにアクセスするまでのトラブルシューティング](https://qiita.com/vmmhypervisor/items/c8ef0ad87318656facb2)が良いようです。

詳細についてはまた更新しますが、解決を願います。

[Access Token and Refresh token giving invalid grant in Google Plus in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115933/access-token-and-refresh-token-giving-invalid-grant-in-google-plus-in-python/30117441#30117441)に解法が書いてあると皆いっているようです。私は使ったことがないのでわかりませんが、結構な人がおっしゃっているみたいなのでそうなのでしょう。
　ほかにも回答がありましたが、これに信用度が10ついていましたので引っ張ってみました。
何か心当たりはありませんか？

無効な`grant error`は二つの共通する原因を有する。
1.あなたのサーバーの時計が[NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)と同時的に進行しないためである。
(解決法:そのサーバーの時刻を調べ、もし不一致ならばそれを治しましょう。)
2.`refresh token limit`を超えてしまった。
(解決法:あなたがすることは何もない。使用上それ以上の`refresh token`は持つことが出来ない。)
　アプリケーションは多様な`refresh token`を要求することができる。例えば、これはあるユーザーが多様なマシンに一つのアプリケーションをインストールしたいときなんかに有効である。この場合、二つの`refresh token`が要求されるけれども、それぞれの一つインストールに使われるものとする。`refresh token`の数が、その制限を超えると、古い`token`は、無効になってしまいます。もしそのアプリケーションが無効化された`refresh token`を使おうと試みるならば、ある`invalid_grant error` という反応が返ってきます。それぞれ単独のペア、`OAuth2.0`クライアントのための制限は25　`refresh tokens` です。(この制限は、変わりやすいことを覚えておいてください。）もしそのアプリケーションが、`refresh tokens`を、同じ`Client/Account`ペアのために要求するのであれば、一度26回目の`token`が発行されると、以前発行された最初の`token`は無効になってしまうでしょう。27番目の`token`は、このように、以前の2番目の無効になった`token`になってしまいます。

> Invalid_grant error has two common causes. 
>   1.Your server’s clock is not in sync with NTP. (Solution: check the server time if its incorrect fix it. )
>   2.The refresh token limit has been exceeded. (Solution: Nothing you can do they cant have more refresh tokens in use) Applications can request multiple refresh tokens. For example, this is useful in situations where a user wants to install an application on multiple machines. In this case, two refresh tokens are required, one for each installation. When the number of refresh tokens exceeds the limit, older tokens become invalid. If the application attempts to use an invalidated refresh token, an invalid_grant error response is returned. The limit for each unique pair of OAuth 2.0 client and is 25 refresh tokens (note that this limit is subject to change). If the application continues to request refresh tokens for the same Client/Account pair, once the 26th token is issued, the 1st refresh token that was previously issued will become invalid. The 27th requested refresh token would invalidate the 2nd previously issued token and so on.

それから、じゃあどうすれば、NTPと合わせられるのか？ということについて本家で調べてみたら、
　[Synchronize the server clock to an NTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177055/synchronize-the-server-clock-to-an-ntp-server)に行き当たり、https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791193/php-microtime-drift-external-ntp-service/21805579#21805579で答えを書いたとおっしゃってました。
`php`が、本来の分野らしいのですが、共通の解法が匂えばいいかなと思って載せてみました。
何か参考になれば幸いです。
　
**追記：**
もう見られたことだろうと思うのですが、日付時刻調整の解説サイトです。
[日付と時刻の設定](https://pc-karuma.net/mac-date-time/)
や
[PCの時刻合わせに公開NTPサーバーを使う](http://neoblog.itniti.net/time-adjustment-open-ntp/)

[すべての時計を合わせたい](http://easy.mri.co.jp/19991026.html)

Comment: アクセストークンについての日本語のサイト[http://www.ari-hiro.com/blog/2012/12/30/oauth2-summary/]

Comment: 他のページやサイトにリンクを貼る際は、「ここ」ではなく元ページのタイトル等で『何が書いてあるページなのか』分かるようにしておくと、より親切だと思います（単に「ここ」だとリンクを開いてみないと何について書かれているのか分からない）。

Comment: 了解です。わかりました。鶏みたいですよね。